# Adding new row in dataframe with conditional split of previous row

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy, dataframe

if 'or' condition is present in a particular column value it has to split and create a new row by previous values in a data frame .tried with split and concate  unable to get desired output any help is highly appreciated
**input**

```
  col1   col2           col3              col4
0  x     bca or cba     value1 or null    x1 or x2
1  y     bca            value2            x1
```

**output**

```
   col1   col2           col3        col4
 0  x     bca            value1      x1
 1  x     cba            null        x2
 2  y     bca            value2      x1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
cols = df.columns

df = (df.join(df.pop('col2')
        .str.split(' or ', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .rename('col2'))
      ).reset_index(drop=True).reindex(columns=cols)
print (df)
  col1 col2    col3
0    x  bca  value1
1    x  cba  value1
2    y  bca  value2
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) column for extract with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column with `expand = True` to `DataFrame`
2. Reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
3. [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for remove first level of `MultiIndex`
4. `rename` `Series` by new column name
5. Then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original df
6. Function [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) is necessary for unique index
7. Last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same order of columns names

EDIT:

```
df = (df.set_index('col1')
        .stack()
        .str.split(' or ', expand=True)
        .stack()
        .unstack(1)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index()

)
print (df)

  col1 col2    col3 col4
0    x  bca  value1   x1
1    x  cba    null   x2
2    y  bca  value2   x1
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael for you detail explination

Comment: @jezral - any way to pop multiple columns ?

Comment: @AshokkumarP - Can you explain more?

Comment: df.pop() will support only one  column at a time

Comment: @AshokkumarP - yes, but then need another solution - because is necessary split each column with `or`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184381/discussion-between-ashok-kumar-p-and-jezrael).

Comment: @AshokkumarP - There is same number of `or` for each column like in question? Not possible like first value in `col4` - `x1 or x2 or x5` ? Or `x1` only ?

Comment: there is only one or condition in the values & same number of or for each column

Comment: @jezrael- i really appreciate your time and effort . if the duplicate values in index column again it will be a trouble right?

Comment: @AshokkumarP - Are data confidental?

Comment: @ jezrael-if you want to give a try on data i can share the sample

Comment: @AshokkumarP - You can send me data to my email from my profile.